# What does a lot of 'STOPPED' messages in bash mean?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having a weird issue. Sometimes on a quite loaded server i get a bunch of :

```
# apt-get install sun-java6-jre
[1]+  Stopped                 apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

or even

```
# (just hitting Return)
[1]+  Stopped                 apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-fonts
```

And then i can't do anything; all that does is returning me this 'stopped' line ...

What does that mean ? Too many processes ? How can i solve this ...

Comment: It means you've got jobs running in the background - maybe ones that would like to communicate with the user (to report that they've completed, perhaps, or to get an answer to a question, or ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+Stopped` means someone (probably an admin) sent the process a `SIGTSTP` (STOP signal) which puts the process on hold (using [Job Control](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_77.html)). It's the same what happens when you press Ctrl+Z.

This can probably be automated to keep runaway processes in check on a loaded server.

To resume the process, try "fg".

Comment: This is a pretty good hint considering the OP mentioned 'on a quite loaded server' +1

Comment: or `bg` to resume it in the background (as if you'd started it with a & at the end)

Answer (score 2):

See [Job Control](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_77.html)

You can use

```
jobs # list the background jobs (by id number)

fg # to foreground the last background job

fg 3 # to foregroun background job with id '3'
```

---

<sub>Note: ***sometimes*** people will inadvertently spawn jobs in the background by failing to escape special characters:</sub>

```
 wget http://sample.org/file.txt?ts=122&uid=guest
```

instead of

```
 wget 'http://sample.org/file.txt?ts=122&uid=guest'
```

Comment: tried : "jobs" and still have that stopped message coming ...

Comment: all i did was apt-get update, so no mistake about a background task typo.